# Maya's Render.exe: preRender and postRender flags generating errors

Tags: python, python-3.5, maya, mel

I'm generating .bat and .sh scripts to launch Maya's batch render for many scenes (I use the AMD FireRender as a renderer).

```py
cmds.append('''"{tool}" -log "{log_path}" -proj "{project}" -r FireRender -devc "{render_device}" -rd "{result_dir}" -im "{img_name}" -preRender "python(\\"import base_functions\\"); python(\\"base_functions.main({case_num})\\");" -postRender "python(\\"base_functions.post_render({case_num})\\");" "{scene}"'''.format(
            tool=args.tool,
            log_path=os.path.join(work_dir, LOGS_DIR, case['case'] + '.log'),
            project=projPath,
            result_dir=os.path.join(work_dir, 'Color'),
            img_name=case['case'],
            render_device=args.render_device,
            case_num=case_num,
            scene=case['scene']
        ));
```

`cmds` is a list with commands that will be written into the script later.
`base_functions` is a python script for logging and executing mel commands for each case.

For example, if I have two cases with `default.ma` scene, the resulting `script.bat` will be:

```
"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2020\bin\Render.exe" -log "F:/Workspace/Work/jobs_test_maya/Work/Results/Maya/Smoke\render_tool_logs\MAYA_SM_001.log" -proj "C:/TestResources/MayaAssets\Smoke\default" -r FireRender -devc "gpu" -rd "F:/Workspace/Work/jobs_test_maya/Work/Results/Maya/Smoke\Color" -im "MAYA_SM_001" -preRender "python(\"import base_functions\"); python(\"base_functions.main(0)\");" -postRender "python(\"base_functions.post_render(0)\");" "default.ma"
"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2020\bin\Render.exe" -log "F:/Workspace/Work/jobs_test_maya/Work/Results/Maya/Smoke\render_tool_logs\MAYA_SM_002.log" -proj "C:/TestResources/MayaAssets\Smoke\default" -r FireRender -devc "gpu" -rd "F:/Workspace/Work/jobs_test_maya/Work/Results/Maya/Smoke\Color" -im "MAYA_SM_002" -preRender "python(\"import base_functions\"); python(\"base_functions.main(1)\");" -postRender "python(\"base_functions.post_render(1)\");" "default.ma"
```

When I execute this script, images are rendered, but in each log I have two errors:

```
Error: line 0: setAttr: Too much data was provided. The last 5 elements were not used.

Error: line 0: setAttr: Too much data was provided. The last 2 elements were not used.
```

They appear because of the `-preRender` and `-postRender` flags respectively.
I could ignore these errors, but I need to get images exactly similar to the reference ones, which does not work yet, and this error haunts me.
Maybe I use these flags in a wrong way?

Comment: And the procedures which are called in the pre- and postrender procedures work fine from within maya?

Comment: Yeah, procedures work, but errors appear due to these flags.

Comment: You could try to simplify the python code a little bit so that you get strings without backslashes like this: `"python('import base_functions;base_functions.main(0)')"`